# How you remove extra space underneath a div

Tags: html, css

I have an empty div in my html file, then I have a css file that declares the size of this div using an id. I sized my div vertically to size of my homepage, however the page extends at the bottom and there is that unneeded extra space. 
How can you I remove it?
Below is my html:

```css
body {
padding: 0;
margin:0;
height: 50%;
width: 1500px;
}
#box{
background-color: white;
width: 450px;
height: 590px;
margin: 69px 0%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My Page</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myPage.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id = "box">
 </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link in your question to add your code.

Comment: add some of yout HTML/CSS code

Comment: Please give us the relevant code - nobody can do more than speculate without it.

Comment: Well, you added it yourself using `margin: 69px 0%`, changing that to `margin: 69px 0 0;` will probably solve your issue

Comment: To extend what @LGSon said, `margin: 69px 0%;` is short hand. When only two properties are provided the first value is `top` AND `bottom` margin and the second value is `right` AND `left` margin. For simplicity and your use case, being more explicit might be preferable. Replace `margin: 69px 0%;` with `margin-top: 69px;`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you don't need to use body height and width. Any Question Ask Me on comment. :)

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 450px;
  height: 590px;
  margin-top: 69px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#box h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My Page</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myPage.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div id = "box">
      <h1>Title</h1>
 </div>
   </body>
</html>
```